# Google Maps Marker not visible after code moved to existing app

Tags: css, google-maps, canvas, google-maps-api-3, marker

I have looked at several posts about missing markers and no solutions seem to apply here. I have reduced the problem down to rendering a very basic map with one marker with a hard-coded location. Chrome dev debugging indicates that the marker exists and should be visible, but it doesn't display. Furthermore, I can implement an Infowindow fine given the map and marker, but the marker is hidden.

Working code for just a plain web page with this simple map of the U.S. with one marker in the middle:

```
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>

  <div style="height:500px" id = "map-canvas"> </div>

  <script>
      var myMap;
      var marker;

  function mapInitialize() {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(35,-96);
      var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  }

  myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: myMap,
      position: latlng,
      title:"Hello World!",
      visible: true
  });

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', mapInitialize);

</script>
```

Now, here is the code in a Backbone map view. I have not implemented a marker collection and wonder if I may need to based on other posts. I have moved everything into an initialize function to simplify the code for troubleshooting. But I have just one point for now.

```
var MapView = Backbone.View.extend ({

 el: "body",

 initialize: function() {

     var myMap;
     var marker;
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(35,-96);
     var mapOptions = {
         zoom: 4,
         center: latlng,
         mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
   }

   myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
   marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       map: myMap,
       position: latlng,
       title:"Hello World!",
       visible: true
   });

 }
});
```

plain page (/map.html)
[image: plain page]
with Backbone (/#/map, where route calls for creation of new MapView via the code above)
[image: Backbone page]

In Chrome Dev, properties for "marker" in both:

```
position: df
    B: -96
    k: 35
title: "Hello World!
visible: true
```

In addition

```
marker.map === myMap
```

evaluates to true, so it appears the marker is being associated with the map.

Answer (score 0):

My Backbone code was part of an existing application. In order to see if Backbone itself had any role in the problem, I added the map view to a brand new Backbone app with none of the code of the existing app. The marker showed up just fine.

Upon examining the properties of the elements generated, I located the canvas object that the marker is rendered in with the overall Google map canvas.

```
<div style="-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; 
 z-index: 103; width: 100%;”>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: -1;”>
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1;”>
            <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; 
             -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 230px; 
              top: 27px;”>
                <canvas style="-webkit-user-select: none; position: absolute; 
                 left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 256px; width: 256px;”>
```

Explicitly setting the canvas element's display style property to a value other than "none" fixed the problem. Why did I have to do this? Because buried in the CSS for this sprawling app was

```
canvas {
  display: none;
}
```

This was in here for a module in the app completely unrelated to Google maps.